# Going to next target element when click target element

Tags: intro.js

Is there a way to customize the introJs script to go to next element when user click over the targetElement?

http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

Answer (score 1):

If the user is already within an introJs tour then you can use the goToStep function. Like this:

`introJs().goToStep(2);`

If you are trying to create something like a help system then you would want to start each step individually and then have the user exit that step so that they could click on the next element in your page. That would look something like this.

`introJs().goToStep(2).start(); //starts introduction from step 2`